# Dexie Js not working on mobile

Tags: ionic-framework, indexeddb, dexie

I'm trying to use the indexedDb wrapper, Dexie js for local data persistence in an hybride mobile app in Ionic 3. On browser everything works fine . but when I build the app on android it seems to not working. Could someone help me ?